# Correct div.class combination when scraping with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to pull out the list of constituencies in the table on this website using rvest: https://labour.org.uk/activist-hub/governance-and-legal-hub/selections/parliamentary-candidate-application-form/

This is what I have so far, which kind of gets me what I want:

```
open <- rvest::read_html('https://labour.org.uk/activist-hub/governance-and-legal-hub/selections/parliamentary-candidate-application-form/')

open %>% 
   html_nodes("div.col")
```

Which currently returns this:

```
{xml_nodeset (14)}
 [1] <div class="col" style="width:30%">\n        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSeat        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>
 [2] <div class="col" style="width:70%">\n        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDeadline        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>
 [3] <div class="col" style="width:30%">\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<h6>Blackpool North and Fleetwood</h6>\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>
 [4] <div class="col" style="width:70%">\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<ul>\n<li>12 Noon, Thursday 6 July</li>\t\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</ul>\n</div>
 [5] <div class="col" style="width:30%">\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<h6>Caerfryddin</h6>\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>
 [6] <div class="col" style="width:70%">\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<ul>\n<li>12 Noon, Friday 7 July</li>\t\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</ul>\n</div>
 [7] <div class="col" style="width:30%">\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<h6>Great Yarmouth</h6>\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>
 [8] <div class="col" style="width:70%">\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<ul>\n<li>12 Noon, Thursday 6 July</li>\t\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</ul>\n</div>
 [9] <div class="col" style="width:30%">\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<h6>Hemel Hempstead</h6>\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>
[10] <div class="col" style="width:70%">\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<ul>\n<li>12 Noon, Thursday 6 July</li>\t\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</ul>\n</div>
[11] <div class="col" style="width:30%">\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<h6>Leeds South West and Morley</h6>\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>
[12] <div class="col" style="width:70%">\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<ul>\n<li>12 Noon, Thursday 6 July</li>\t\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</ul>\n</div>
[13] <div class="col" style="width:30%">\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<h6>South Derbyshire</h6>\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>
[14] <div class="col" style="width:70%">\n\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<ul>\n<li>12 Noon, Thursday 6 July</li>\t\t        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</ul>\n</div>
```

What I want is a clean tibble that includes the constituency name in one column and the date in the second column. Can anyone give me some pointers on the correct css selector please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did all of the hard work.  Now it is just a matter of separating the 'style="width:30%"' from the 'style="width:70%"'.  There are a couple ways of doing this.
Below I look at the "style" attribute and separate them into 2 different vectors which I create the final answer from.  I needed to delete the first row since that contained the column names.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

open <- read_html('https://labour.org.uk/activist-hub/governance-and-legal-hub/selections/parliamentary-candidate-application-form/')

nodes <- open %>% html_nodes("div.col")

seat <- nodes[html_attr(nodes, "style") == "width:30%" ] %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
deadline <- nodes[html_attr(nodes, "style") == "width:70%" ] %>% html_text() %>% trimws()

data.frame(seat, deadline)[-1,]
                           seat                 deadline
1 Blackpool North and Fleetwood 12 Noon, Thursday 6 July
2                   Caerfryddin   12 Noon, Friday 7 July
3                Great Yarmouth 12 Noon, Thursday 6 July
4               Hemel Hempstead 12 Noon, Thursday 6 July
5   Leeds South West and Morley 12 Noon, Thursday 6 July
6              South Derbyshire 12 Noon, Thursday 6 July
```

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference in such cases is to keep related elements together to handle missing/unmatched values. Here it would be a list of "rows":

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

url_ <- "https://labour.org.uk/activist-hub/governance-and-legal-hub/selections/parliamentary-candidate-application-form/"
read_html(url_) %>% 
  # select a list of "rows"
  html_elements("div.two-column-list__body > div") %>% 
  # iterate through rows, if there are missing values, 
  # seat and deadline would still be correctly aligned;
  # list of named lists from map() plays well with dplyr::bind_rows()
  map(\(row_div)
      list(seat     = html_element(row_div, "div.col > h6") %>% html_text(),
           deadline = html_element(row_div, "div.col > ul > li") %>% html_text())) %>% 
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   seat                          deadline                
#>   <chr>                         <chr>                   
#> 1 Blackpool North and Fleetwood 12 Noon, Thursday 6 July
#> 2 Caerfryddin                   12 Noon, Friday 7 July  
#> 3 Great Yarmouth                12 Noon, Thursday 6 July
#> 4 Hemel Hempstead               12 Noon, Thursday 6 July
#> 5 Leeds South West and Morley   12 Noon, Thursday 6 July
#> 6 South Derbyshire              12 Noon, Thursday 6 July
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>