# How to control for character(0)?

Tags: r, rvest, tibble

I was wondering whether I could get some thoughts on the following issue:

When scraping multiple elements from multiple websites with `rvest`, it can easily happen that one requested html_element doesn't exist on e.g. one single site. Consequently, rvest
returns, at least in my example below, `character(0)`.

Including such a `character(0)` element into a tibble does not render the pertaining
column/value NA, but renders the entire tibble to a zero row tibble (if the tibble would otherwise have only one row).

I hope the example below makes this clearer.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

#Here my urls:
vec_urls <- c("https://www.noe.gv.at/noe/Achau.html", "https://www.noe.gv.at/noe/Aderklaa.html")

#Here the scraping function iterating over the urls:

fn_get_address <- function(municip_url) {

municip_name <-{{municip_url}} %>%
rvest::read_html()  %>%
rvest::html_elements(., xpath="//h1[@data-cms-title='Name der Gemeinde']/text()") %>%
html_text() 

municip_web <- {{municip_url}} %>%
rvest::read_html() %>%
rvest::html_elements(.,xpath="//div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-12') and .//*[contains(text(), 'Kontakt:')]]")  %>%
rvest::html_elements("a") %>%
rvest::html_attr("href") %>%
stringr::str_subset(., regex("www"))

tibble("municip_name"=municip_name, "municip_web"=municip_web)

}

fn_get_address(vec_urls[1]) #works
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   municip_name municip_web           
#>   <chr>        <chr>                 
#> 1 Achau        http://www.achau.gv.at

fn_get_address(vec_urls[2]) # doesn't work; returns 0 row tibble
#> # A tibble: 0 × 2
#> # ℹ 2 variables: municip_name <chr>, municip_web <chr>
```

The reason why `vec_urls[2]` returns a 0 row tibble is the fact that
`municip_web` returns `character(0)`. It doesn't exist in the source. When combined to a tibble, the entire tibble becomes a zero-row tibble.

```r
municip_web_2 <- vec_urls[2]  %>%
rvest::read_html() %>%
rvest::html_elements(.,xpath="//div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-12') and .//*[contains(text(), 'Kontakt:')]]")  %>%
rvest::html_elements("a") %>%
rvest::html_attr("href") %>%
stringr::str_subset(., regex("www"))
municip_web_2 #character(0)
#> character(0)

municip_name_2 <- vec_urls[2] %>%
rvest::read_html()  %>%
rvest::html_elements(., xpath="//h1[@data-cms-title='Name der Gemeinde']/text()") %>%
html_text() 
municip_name_2 #ok
#> [1] "Aderklaa"

#combining leads to zero row tibble
tibble("municip_name"=municip_name_2, "municip_web"=municip_web_2)
#> # A tibble: 0 × 2
#> # ℹ 2 variables: municip_name <chr>, municip_web <chr>
```

So, here's my question: Since we can never exclude the possibility that a html element
returns character(0) there's always a chance that a tibble get's lost.
What is your way to control for this? Unless, I am mistaken, this would also mean
we should never use tibble(.... ) when scraping since we can never exclude the absence of some html elements on some page?

My current approach is the following, which works, but I was wondering
whether there isn't another solution which is more straightforward.

```r
list("municip_name"=municip_name_2, "municip_web"=municip_web_2)  %>%
modify_if(., .p=is_empty, \(x) NA) %>%
enframe() %>% pivot_wider() %>%unnest(cols=everything())
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   municip_name municip_web
#>   <chr>        <lgl>      
#> 1 Aderklaa     NA
```

I am very curious to learn how others are approaching this issue.
Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you write `{{municip_url}}` instead of `municip_url`? The `{{…}}` do nothing here. `municip_url` is a regular parameter, and neither `%>%` nor the function you’re piping it into (`rvest::read_html()`) are doing anything special with it.

Comment: Oh, and quoting the arguments to `tibble()` is also a questionable practice: after all, you are not quoting variable names in assignment (`x" <- 1`) either, right?

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640161/r-how-to-test-for-character0-in-if-statement

Comment: @KonradRudolph "questionable practice"? I'd think "questionable" would be reserved for doing things that could come back to bite you, is there a time quoting names is problematic? Quoting the names in `tibble` seems a normally-innocent practice that may be useful one time somebody chooses to have a non-standard name and their tibble-technique remains consistent.

Comment: @r2evans I definitely think that “questionable” is appropriate here, given that the rules around string-quoting syntactic names in R is so confusing that even advanced R users misunderstand them, and the fact that these rules are the result of incredibly poor language design, and should ideally be removed from the language altogether. Fundamentally, treating variable names and strings (two fundamentally different entities!) identically is such an obviously terrible idea that I feel it weird having to justify why it’s bad.

Comment: Okay, so perhaps a more consistent method would be to use backticks here? @KonradRudolph

Comment: @r2evans Sure, but backticks only make sense for non-syntactic names, but the names used by OP are entirely syntactic. If you used backticks here, then why not for *every* name usage?

Comment: I guess that's part of my point. I agree that we don't need to use backticks everywhere, _and I do not_, but is there harm using it when it is not required? Said differently, is this a not-common **technique** that has no detrimental effect on the parsed code, or is there the possibility that it may introduce problems? @KonradRudolph

Comment: @r2evans The harm in *every* bit of added clutter is that it makes the code minimally more messy and thus worse. Individually this won’t have a measurable impact, but clutter compounds. Apply the [Boy Scout rule](https://wiki.c2.com/?BoyScoutRule).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the test "identical()", to check if the part of you function returns character(0), and then change that to e.g. NA

```
fn_get_address <- function(municip_url) {
  
  municip_name <-{{municip_url}} %>%
    rvest::read_html()  %>%
    rvest::html_elements(., xpath="//h1[@data-cms-title='Name der Gemeinde']/text()") %>%
    html_text() 
  
  municip_web <- {{municip_url}} %>%
    rvest::read_html() %>%
    rvest::html_elements(.,xpath="//div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-12') and .//*[contains(text(), 'Kontakt:')]]")  %>%
    rvest::html_elements("a") %>%
    rvest::html_attr("href") %>%
    stringr::str_subset(., regex("www"))
  
  if (identical(municip_web, character(0)))
    municip_web <- NA
  
  tibble("municip_name"=municip_name, "municip_web"=municip_web)
  
}
```

Comment: Very helpful use of identical! Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To handle cases where document structure does not include all elements for every entity, you could iterate over container elements, collect data into a list of named lists or vectors and pass it to `bind_rows()`. One such example can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76619623/646761

But in this particular case, it's not really an issue as all contact details are in a well-structured table. Though we can still use quite similar pattern to avoid a call to `tibble()` while reducing the number of requests by half:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

vec_urls <- c("https://www.noe.gv.at/noe/Achau.html", "https://www.noe.gv.at/noe/Aderklaa.html")

fn_get_contacts <- function(municip_url) {
  html <- read_html(municip_url)
  
  municip <- 
    html_element(html, xpath="//h1[@data-cms-title='Name der Gemeinde']/text()") |>
    html_text() |>
    setNames("municip")
  
  cont <- 
    html_element(html, xpath="//div[contains(@class, 'col-xs-12') and .//*[contains(text(), 'Kontakt:')]]/table") |>
    html_table() |>
    tibble::deframe()
  
  c(municip, cont) # return a named vector
}
  
fn_get_contacts(vec_urls[2])
#>                   municip                  Telefon:                      Fax: 
#>                "Aderklaa"         "(0 22 47) 22 90"                        "" 
#>                   E-Mail:                 Homepage: 
#> "gemeinde@aderklaa.gv.at"                        ""

lapply(vec_urls, fn_get_contacts) |>
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   municip  `Telefon:`       `Fax:`                `E-Mail:`          `Homepage:`
#>   <chr>    <chr>            <chr>                 <chr>              <chr>      
#> 1 Achau    (0 22 36) 715 83 "(0 22 36) 715 83 33" office@achau.gv.at "www.achau…
#> 2 Aderklaa (0 22 47) 22 90  ""                    gemeinde@aderklaa… ""
```

Comment: FYI, in case you don’t know it yet, core R has `stats::setNames()`.

Comment: many thanks. deframe and using a named vector is a new approach to me.